# What is the limit to how much you can increase rotational speed using gears?

Tags: rotational-dynamics

Sometimes, gears are used to increase or decrease the rotational speed of a motor. This can be done using gears with different sizes. For example: putting a large gear next to a smaller gear and turning the larger gear will output a higher turning speed through the smaller gear. The opposite affect will be achieved if you do it the other way. I'm wondering if there is a limit to how much you can amplify the speed by putting larger gears to smaller gears.

Picture to show what I mean (excuse my bad drawing skills)[image]

Comment: The limit is dependent of the physical properties of the material used to make the gears. Eventually even steel breaks if you spin it fast enough, let alone push it against something spinning in the opposite direction.

Comment: Going the other way has already been done as an art work:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5q-BH-tvxEg   , and another at https://blog.adafruit.com/2020/03/06/the-universes-biggest-gear-reduction-art-mechanics/

Comment: Relevant video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QwXK4e4uqXY

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In principle you are free to add as many gears as you like to a train of gears arranged so that each gear increases the speed of the next by some factor.

Let's suppose the gears where designed so that each stage in the train increased the speed of rotation of the next by a factor of ten. If you had, say, twenty stages, then the speed of the final stage would be 100,000,000,000,000,000,000 times the speed of the first.

You would encounter a number of practical problems in making such a train work. Firstly, as each stage increases the speed of the next, so does it reduce its turning effort. That means that if you required 1 unit of torque to turn the final stage in the train, then you would need to apply at least 100,000,000,000,000,000,000 units to turn the first stage.

Secondly, the materials out of which the gears were made would have to be strong enough to cope with the turning forces, the forces being strongest in the first stage of the train.

Thirdly, the materials would also have to be sufficiently strong to cope with the centrifugal effect, the forces being strongest on the final stage of the train.

Fourthly, the materials would have to withstand the heat generated by friction of the bearings.

You can address these challenges by making the gears out of light but strong materials, by running the train in a vacuum (which minimises air resistance and thus the turning force required) and by refrigerating the bearings. All these techniques are used in high-speed centrifuges, the fastest of which claims to rotate at around 150,000 rpm, generating a centrifugal force of just over one million g.

Given the above, it would seem prudent to assume that the twenty-stage train would run into problems when the speed of the final stage approached just a million rpm, say, meaning that the speed of the first stage in the train would have to be kept below 0.000000000000001rpm.